# Карточная игра Пьяница

Tags: вектор, c++, структуры

Пишу карточную игру "Пьяница".

```
struct card{

int, rank;
};
vector <card> first, second;
```

Векторы first и second это игроки, card это карта, ну и rank это ранк карты. Оба вектора заполнены по 18 элементов card. Надеюсь принцип игры все знают.

Помогите реализовать саму игру, то есть сравнение карт и подбор карт(кстати, забранные карты нужно класть не в отдельную стопку а под свои, сначала свою потом противника). Игра заканчивается когда у одного из игроков заканчиваются карты.

Может быть не лучший вариант реализации, но начал уже делать и решил добить. Или подскажите как можно лучше это все реализовать.

Comment: По-моему, Вам не vector <person> следует объявлять, а vector <card> first, second;

Не понял состава структуры card: что такое int, rank;?

Comment: @BuilderC зачем отдельно? Всего три одинаковых очереди: карты двух игроков и карты колоды. Структура карты - два инта: номинал и масть (для красоты).

Comment: Я бы сделал через циклический список. У каждого игрока свой. Для выкладываемых на стол карт можно использовать стеки (для каждого игрока свой).

Такая структура данных наиболее естественно соответствует [правилам игры](http://ru.wikipedia.org/wiki/%D0%9F%D1%8C%D1%8F%D0%BD%D0%B8%D1%86%D0%B0_%28%D0%BA%D0%B0%D1%80%D1%82%D0%BE%D1%87%D0%BD%D0%B0%D1%8F_%D0%B8%D0%B3%D1%80%D0%B0%29).

Сравнение карт это очевидно - арифметические операции `>` и `==` (а вообще-то поиск максимума) над вершинами стеков.

Comment: @klopp, я полагал, что в начале игры у каждого по пол-колоды на руке. И отыгранная пара кладется либо на стол, либо под низ той колоды, которая на руке у выигравшего. Давно не игрывал я в пьяницу.

Comment: BTW, [что нашлось](http://xxo.su/tippler/)! Писалось лет 10 назад, уже не помню зачем и в каком состоянии, в исходник страницы лучше не заглядывать :)

Comment: @klopp,с наслаждением поиграл.

Comment: допустим я инициализировал колоду через очередь, а как потом ее перемешать?

Comment: Можно сначала перемешать массив, да хоть просто `int cards[]`, потом сделать из него очередь. Или через `std::deque<int> x` -> `std::random_shuffle(x.begin(),x.end())`